# How to open a link on browser using ubuntu connected via sssh

Tags: ubuntu, browser, ssh, putty

I have an application which has to open a link on a browser in order to collect information from it [disclaimer: I don't want to use any headless browser].

When I run it on my local machine, everything works good; It opens the link on my default browser and does the work.

now, I have deployed the application on my remote ubuntu machine (which I connect to via putty) but the xdg-open command won't work there. It has its problems like not having GUI server or echo $DISPLAY gives nothing (even tried the DISPLAY=:0 method).

I want to be able to launch a browser at the end of the day and do my work. Then I was thinking it it is possible to open a browser on my local system via a command in my script on the server?

Comment: What operating system are you running on the local system? Are you running an X server on the local system? Are you running putty with the option to forward X?

Comment: windows 10 on local, Ubuntu 16.04.3 on remote. No there's no X server on local (win) and no, putty hasn't been configured to forward X option. I'm pretty new to these things, thus discovering slowly these steps @Kenster